# Snippets aren't working emacs-lsp / company-mode

Tags: lsp

For whatever reason, snippets aren't working. I am getting the placeholders but I cannot navigate between them. This is the type of snippet completion that I am getting:

```lua
for ${1:index}, ${2:value} in ipairs(${3:t}) do
    $0
end
```

I can see the syntax for using snippets but they aren't working. This is my configuration for lsp and company mode.

```lisp
  (use-package lsp-mode
    :ensure t
    :hook
    (go-mode . lsp-deferred)
    (js-mode . lsp-deferred)
    (haskell-mode . lsp-deferred)
    (lua-mode . lsp-deferred)
    :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
    :config
    (define-key lsp-mode-map (kbd "C-l C-l") lsp-command-map))
  #+end_src
- also using lsp-ui to give more of an IDE feel to emacs
  #+begin_src elisp
  (use-package lsp-ui :ensure t)
  #+end_src
- the documentation of what I am using can be found [[https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/main-features/][here]]

*** Company-mode

- this mode allows for an autocomplete window to popup as you code
- i had it enabled in all buffers but was not a huge fan of this so I bound it to the vim COC control space keybinding to initialize it 
  #+begin_src elisp
  (use-package company
    :ensure t
    :bind ("C-SPC" . company-mode))
  ;;(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode) not a fan of it in every mode 
  #+end_src

- the "recommended settings"
  #+begin_src elisp
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1
        company-idle-delay 0.0) ;; default is 0.2
  (setq company-selection-wrap-around t)
  #+end_src
```

Comment: Maybe remove as much as possible from the code you show, to minimize interactions. E.g., is haskell-mode relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to configure yasnippet for it to work it is working now.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer your own question - but I'm afraid it may be deleted by voters who think the quality is too low. Could you elaborate a bit more on how you solved your problem so that others may better benefit from your experience? Then your answer may even get some upvotes instead of being deleted.